# Unexpected Python String Encoding of '/b'

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding, spyder

I am very new to python, so please be kind.

I defined a list of strings (which are Windows 7 file paths):

```
iso_8859_files = ['dtSystem\delta3d\ext\inc\cpl_win32ce_api.h',
                  'dtSystem\delta3d\ext\inc\cpl_wince.h',
                  'dtSystem\delta3d\src\dtABC\beziercontroller.cpp',
                  'dtSystem\delta3d\src\dtDirectorNodes\dividemutator.cpp']
```

However, when i print the list to console I get:

```
['dtSystem\\delta3d\\ext\\inc\\cpl_win32ce_api.h', 'dtSystem\\delta3d\\ext\\inc\\cpl_wince.h', 'dtSystem\\delta3d\\src\\dtABC\x08eziercontroller.cpp', 'dtSystem\\delta3d\\src\\dtDirectorNodes\\dividemutator.cpp']
```

If you compare the before/after of the third string in the list, there seems to be an encoding error occurring with the character '\b'.  Is there a way to setup the list to ensure the encoding does not change?

Comment: You may try prepending r' to your strings so as to tell python not to escape the backslashes (r' is raw_mode)

Comment: You need to use raw stings: `r'path\file.cpp'`

Comment: Also: the `\b` is being changed because \ is an escape character. See the duplicate question for information on this.

Comment: Apologize for duplicate question, was searching for a completely different question than one answered.  Regardless, switching to raw strings worked.  Thank you for quick help!